# Why I am not able to add certificates to keystore?

Tags: java, keytool

I tried to add my certificate into keystore and as I do not have admin rights on my machine I was given access denied error. I am using jdk1.8.0_20 and the directory where I was trying to add the certificate is `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\security"`

The commands I ran are below :

```
keytool -importcert -alias "Certificate.cer" -file  C:\Certificate.cer -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
```

Do you think now I will need to do this programmatically and then I will be able to get it working? Coz later I have to push it in a cloud as well to deploy in DEV environment.

Comment: If you don't have admin rights you won't be able to edit an admin folder...